# NG for and Bootstrap grid displaced downwards

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid-layout

[image]

Hello together,

I got a small problem which I absolutely can´t fix and can´t reproduce.

The creation looks like:

```
<div class='wrapper row warp-field col-md-12 col-12'>
<ng-template ngFor let-i="index" let-c="count" let-weeks [ngForOf]=" pagedItems">
    <div class=' weekBlock row col-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4'>
        <div class="weekHeader col-12"><h1>1</h1>1</div>
        <div class="shift col-4 col-md-4 col-xlg-4" *ngFor="let shifts of weeks | slice:1 ; let i2 = index;" >
            <div class="wrapper col-12 col-md-12" *ngFor="let departments of shifts | slice:1 ; let i3 = index; ">
                <div class="col-12 departmentHead" [ngSwitch]="i3 + 1">
                    <h4 *ngSwitchCase="1"> X </h4>
                    <h4 *ngSwitchCase="2"> Y </h4>
                </div>
                <div class='personBlock row col-12 col-md-12' *ngFor="let people of departments; let i4 = index;">
                    <div class='pTopRow col-6 col-md-6'>
                        <h5 class="leftText"></h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class='pTopRow col-6 col-md-6'>
                        <h5 class="rightText"> </h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="pFooter col-12">
                        <ul class="Days">
                            <li> MO</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

So it works fine on small screens on big screens there 3 columns beeing displayed, the second is misplaced downwards.

```
<div class="weekHeader col-12"><h1>1</h1>1</div>
```

If I remove this row (the blue area) the layout works fine. Somehow only in the second column this block gets created to big. I tried to set this div to fixed height but the block under it stays misplaced. The div has only 1 custom css property and this is "text-align: center"

What I tried until now:

- Removing weekHeader (works but I need it)
- Set the height of weekHeader fixed to X px //height does change but position keeps the same
- Set the class shift block to top:0 //Not working but if I change it to top -6px in the developer console its working. The funny thing is after it I can increase it back to top: 0px and its working -.- Predefining it to -6px does not change anything
- Changing weekHeader and shift to row elements //same layout

Edit 1:
- Tried adding clearfix on nearly every section no change.

Answer (score 0):

Found my Solution:
- had just to set the parent row element to any height value. It actually did made no difference if I define it with 100% or 10%. It just started working. Min-height wasn´t enough.